# MYSQL: How to export columns containing HTML to CSV or Excel?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a query which returns 6 columns in my result. One of the columns has HTML in it while the others are text or numbers. The result looks good when I view it in MYSQL Workbench, however, when I export it to CSV or Excel, the column containing HTML is scattered everywhere.

Is there a way I can export to CSV/Excel and not have the values scattered? Thanks in advance.

MYSQL Workbench display
[image]

Output in Excel
[image]

Comment: The HTML text you're exporting contains, amongst other things, quotes, commas and new lines, all of which will cause potential difficulties with CSV output. It might be possible to import into Excel using a different format, but why do you need to import lengthy HTML strings into Excel at all?

Comment: Potentially, if you could export with each of the non-html columns first, each with a fixed width, then the last column in each row with the html, you could then import the text file into Excel as fixed-width, basically setting the width of the non-html columns, and then Excel will just take the remainder as the last column.  When exporting the HTML you will probably need to strip out any line-break characters.  In order to get the fixed widths, and strip out the line-break characters, you'll need to export the results of a query, not just export directly from the table

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to export the query output to a .html file and then saved the .html as .xls and that solved my issue. Rather a simple solution after I spent so much time ripping my hair out lol.

Comment: How were you able to export it ro HTML from phpmyadmin? Thanks in advance!